# highlight or bold option from DropDownList when compared to another variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight a value taken from a dropdownlist when compared to `sysYearMonth` defined in the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sysDate = new Date();
    var sysYear = sysDate.getFullYear();
    var sysMonth = sysDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var sysYearMonth = sysYear + (sysMonth < 10 ? '0' : '') + sysMonth;
    var month = $('#MyDropDownId').text();
    $.each(month,
        function() {
            if (month == sysYearMonth) {
                // code to highlight or bold the option in the selected dropdown
            }
        });
    }
);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to correctly select the two values and how to highlight or bold when the value is found in the dropdown values.
I'm a total noob in jquery so please don't lapidate me:)
Thank you!

Comment: Is `#MyDropDownId` a `select` element containing `option`? If so note that styling individual options is not very well supported cross-browser. Seeing the HTML would help here

Comment: Hi Rory,
This is a dropdown populated by Entity Framework behind the scene.
`code` (<div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownId", ViewBag.ViewBagName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "DropDown Name", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: 100%", @onchange = "someFunction();", @required = true })
                </div>)  `code`

Comment: And to properly answer the question, Yes, it is a select element, containing option.